# Windows 10 PATH / Environmental Variable headaches

Tags: windows, command-line, environment-variables

So I tried to install Windows 10 Debug SDK for KD.exe and it's supposed to be recognized in CMD after a reboot..however command not recognized. Command NEVER recognized, I always have to manually find out what environmental paths were SUPPOSED to be applied, am I installing software wrong? NPM had this issue too, Chocolatey etc. So I'm frustrated in thinking perhaps it's my environment however I  have tried this on three different machines, so I can therefore Isolate that I MUST be doing something wrong.

Please, how do I get programs to properly install the appropriate Environment Path? In Windows XP it used to be so easy and straight forward..

Comment: Nothing has changed since XP, though. Maybe your %PATH% variable is too long or whatever.

Comment: Checking my environment variables -> Path -> it shows C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\

which seems right

Comment: Windows Performance Toolkit will most definitely not have the Kernel Debugger.

Comment: Then the environment variables did not get recorded at all, but the files are there in program files